# Managing state changes caused by an API patch

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack, ngrx

I have a data table that is populated GUI -> API call -> node backend -> loop back -> mongo db. Just displaying data works fine using NGRX state management. I use a modal dialog to edit one of the fields, trigger a submit change action, call the relevant patch API and successfully update the relevant record(s).

In order to reflect this changed record in the GUI. I call the get API when the SUCCESSFUL_SUBMIT action comes. This works fine, but i think it's not the correct way to do things with NGRX and I worry that this will cause maintenance problems in the future.

So my question is, how do i reflect the changed state in the GUI. Please note that I do not wish to display the change in the GUI until i know that the  DB patch was successful.

The image shows the table with the console log having just submitted a change to auto archive.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems fine to me, but:

- if the POST object reflects the GET object and if the server doesn't modify properties, you could update your store without the extra GET
- the POST response body could include the object to prevent the extra GET

Comment: regarding "the POST response body could include the object to prevent the extra GET", i like this but im unsure about the implementation. e.g. if I have Policies[ ] and I only change/ POST a single Policy, how do I get NGRX to update the Policies[ ] part of the state?

Comment: do you mean that your GET returns a list, and now you want to know how to update one single entity from the list?

Comment: Yes exactly, maybe its relevant to the question so it can be added to your answer?

Comment: It all depends on the structure that you're using. For example if you're using @ngrx/entity you can use the updateOne method, otherwise you'll have to update the entity manually. This can be done by finding the entity you have to update and replace it with its new value.

Comment: bang on the money. Owe you a coffee